# How do I assign disparate events from one source to a keyed stream?

Tags: apache-flink

Apologies if the question alone indicates a lack of knowledge. I have a single source that I've split (via side output) based on some value of a key in events processed. 3/4 unique event types have a key I can use to ensure they belong to the same complete transaction but the 4th event can only be paired by some timestamp criteria - there may be n > 1 events like this that need pairing. Here's an example of a food order delivery system;

```
Event1: {'order_id' : xxx, 'event_type' : 'order_confirmed', 'ts' : IS8601} 
Event2: {'order_id' : xxx, 'vehicle_number' : yyy, 'event_type' : 'order_picked_up_by_driver', 'ts' : IS8601} 
**Event3a: {'vehicle_number' : xxx ,'event_type' : 'driver_reached_checkpoint', 'ts' : IS8601} 
**Event3b: {'vehicle_number' : xxx, 'event_type' : 'driver_reached_checkpoint', 'ts' : IS8601 + ~1 hour} 
Event4: {'order_id' : xxx, 'event_type' : 'order_delivered', 'ts' : IS8601 + ~1 hour}
```

Notice how events 1,2 and 4 have an order_id but 3a, 3b are without (though pair-able with event 2). The plan for now is to key events 1,2,4 together by order_id and store state for delivery until 3a,3b are known to be the only events that fit within the range of Event2 and 4s timestamps. Since vehicle number to order_id is a one-to-many relationship I will need to update the driver's state to point to the new order whenever I see a new event 2 and return all events for the previous order for further processing.

Really could use some direction on what I need to solve this even if it is breadcrumb. New to Flink and streaming.

**--- Edits ---**

I want to store state for each order, once I've seen an instance of each event type (multiple in the case of event 3), merge these events together , compute some statistics before outputting to another source and sink. I cannot use a keyed state operator as Event type 3 does not have the key "order_id" available. I can safely assume that the events are ordered.

**Example output, let et = event type**

```
'order_completed_ts' : <et4>, 'number_of_checkpoints_en_route_to_completion' : <et3>}
```

There can be multiple events of the same type for different orders in sequence.

**Sample**

```
1. {'order_id' : 1, 'event_type' : 'order_confirmed', 'ts' : IS8601}
2. {'order_id' : 2, 'event_type' : 'order_confirmed', 'ts' : IS8601}
3. {'order_id' : 3, 'event_type' : 'order_confirmed', 'ts' : IS8601}
4. {'order_id' : 4, 'event_type' : 'order_confirmed', 'ts' : IS8601}
5. {'order_id' : 1, 'event_type' : 'order_picked_up_by_driver', 'ts' : IS8601}
```

- Note how sample element 5 contains the same order id as element 1

Comment: Can driver have more than one order picked at one time ?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for commenting. A driver cannot have more than one order at any given time.

Comment: Okay, also, could you provide the more detailed info (perhaps with example) about what do You exactly want to do ?

Comment: Please let me know if my edits make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, you want the first stage of your pipeline to associate order_ids to the events that don't have them, which will then make the rest of the analysis much more straightforward.

If you use Flink SQL, then this would be a [temporal table join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html), where you join the stream with itself on the `vehicle_number`. You can do this in such a way that each `driver_reached_checkpoint` event will be joined with the latest `order_picked_up_by_driver` event that is before the `driver_reached_checkpoint` event.

Or to do this with the DataStream API, you can key the stream by the `vehicle_number`, and implement a `KeyedProcessFunction` that remembers in keyed state the most recent `order_picked_up_by_driver` event. It can then add the `order_id` from that event to each `driver_reached_checkpoint` event that it sees.

Once you have a stream with an `order_id` on every event, then you can key by the `order_id` (or GROUP BY, if you use SQL).

Comment: Thank you David! Wish I looked at this sooner :).